# Why is my question perfectly fine but another on basically the same thing locked?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked [a question about translating some Elvish with no research effort or anything](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/209400/102999). It's stayed open for a while, and is not contentious on its on-topic-ness.

Enter [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/96984/102999). It is locked, but very highly upvoted. **Why is this? What is wrong with it, but not with my question?**

Comment: Besides having a difficult to confirm backstory and seeming morbid? Unfortunately, for every person who posts a genuine picture of their deceased relative's elvish tattoo, there are probably a dozen who make that kind of thing up for the lolz. The edit history suggests that some people were treating the question under that assumption, which could prove controversial. And when the story behind such questions is true, the potential for hurtful comments or answers trolling the asker is also very high, which might be another reason to lock it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the question content, per se. It's locked not because it's off-topic, but because of some other issues which were highly specific to that question. Don't take the lock on that question as any sort of statement on site scope.

Comment: Well why is it locked? Is it because of the picture?

Comment: @Stormblessed As I said, some other issues. Please be satisfied with that answer. (I wasn't a mod at that time, so even I might not know the full story, but what I do know from the private mod room shouldn't be shared.)

Comment: It's misleading how it says that it's "not because it's a good, **on-topic** question for this site."

Comment: @Stormblessed Lock reasons can't be customised for specific posts.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that that message you have to use makes the reason seem really different from how it actually is.